# How to play a song on mplayer on repeat?

Tags: mplayer

I usually play songs on mplayer through terminal.
However, I don't know to put a song on repeat - as I want to listen to a particular song again and again.

How to put a single song/set of songs on repeat?

Answer (score 37):

Try:

```
mplayer -loop <repeat count>
```

Setting count to zero (`-loop 0`), should repeat it infinitely.

Comment: Is it possible to do this while a song is playing?

Comment: FYI, when doing this for a video it is *not* seamless.